Combining Survey Weights
I have an annual survey that is somewhat complex in design. Sample frames are pulled quarterly and overlap. Each quarter's sample is removed from the subsequent quarter's frame. Samples are stratified by geographic area. The previous owner of the survey treated the sample as if it was self-weighted. However, the multiple frames suggest there is a multiplicity issue. Moreover, only ~6-7% of the sample responds, so non-responses may also be an issue.
I have approached these issues my calculating a multiplicity adjustment based on the work of Hartley (1962). I have also used logistic regression to estimate non-response probabilities. Finally, I have been thinking about raking to adjust to my sample frames; specifically by age and ethnicity.
My only issue is whether I am combining the weights correctly. Here is my approach so far:
Final weight = (1/(sampling probability * non-response probability)) * multiplicity adjustment
Does this look correct?
Would it still be appropriate to rake this "final" weight?

It would be handy to have a little clarification -- by "sample frames overlap" do you mean that there are multiple sampling frames being used within a given quarter? The same goes for multiplicity, the issue being potential selection from multiple sampling frames within a quarter?

p.s. the "multiplicity" tag seems to mostly show up for issues with making multiple comparisons (i.e. type I error rates) rather than overlapping sampling frame concerns, and I'd suggest that could be removed.

As a final comment I'd say your "non-responses may also be an issue" is almost universally true of any survey, ever :-) so definitely important.

No, there is one frame per quarter, but there is overlap with respect to the individuals listed in each frame. If you built a "super frame" of all quarterly frames, some individuals will be in the super frame more than once. Thus, they have a different sampling probability from my understanding.
